# how to convert an array to the shortest string possible

Tags: javascript, hex, base64, radix

I have following array (i'm using JavaScript):

```
var arr = [2, 0, 0, 0, 12]
```

*(Each element of the array can be between `0` to `15`. Length is fixed, 5 elements.)*

I want to convert this array to the shortest string possible. My actual solution is to convert it to an hexadecimal (base16) string:

```
var str = '2000c'
```

Is there a better solution? (I'm looking for a solution in JavaScript, without any library if possible)

Comment: You meant hexadecimal (base16) ?

Comment: What do you mean by encoding an array to a string?

Comment: How are you encoding? adding numbers etc.?

Comment: @Simon yeah probably

Comment: do you need a more compact coding for 0 ... 16^5-1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input is 5 * 4 bits = 20 bits. You can recode your array as a 3-character string (24 bits with an actual payload of 20 bits) and encode it with btoa() to produce a 4-character printable string.

```js
function pack(arr) {
  return btoa(
    String.fromCharCode(
      (arr[1] << 4) | arr[0],
      (arr[3] << 4) | arr[2],
      arr[4]
    )
  );
}

var packed = pack([2, 0, 0, 0, 12]);

console.log(packed); // output: 'AgAM'
```

The unpacking function would use atob() and rebuild the original array like that:

```js
function unpack(packed) {
  var str = atob(packed);
  
  return [
    str.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf,
    str.charCodeAt(0) >> 4,
    str.charCodeAt(1) & 0xf,
    str.charCodeAt(1) >> 4,
    str.charCodeAt(2)
  ];
}

var unpacked = unpack('AgAM');

console.log(unpacked); // output: [ 2, 0, 0, 0, 12 ]
```

Comment: that's really interesting what you got there @Arnauld, would it work too if my array had a fixed length of 24 elements?

Comment: The concept would, you would have to adjust it to 12 characters. Every two values is stored in a single character, with an upper half and lower half. You could extend it to N elements by writing atob into a loop over each index packing it into an ceil(N/2) array of characters.

Comment: @DanielB. is correct. It would work pretty well with 24 elements actually, since Base64 is processing 3-byte packets and you'll have exactly 24 * 4 = 96 bits = 12 bytes = 4 packets of 3 bytes. (Of course, for a larger array, you should consider using a loop rather than the monolithic kind of code I used.)

Comment: @julesbou Note that this solution gives you the shortest length of printable characters. You could also keep it to 3 bytes without converting it to base64.

Comment: @Simon A solution without using base64 would be awesome, care to write an answer?

Comment: What @Simon means -- I think -- is that you could remove this btoa() and directly assign the concatenation of the three String.fromCharCode() to 'packed'. You'll get a string that may or may not include non-printable characters, depending on the input. That's perfectly fine if your goal is to store it in a variable at run-time. But you may not be able to include such a string in a source code -- at least not without escaping non-printable characters, thus losing the benefit of a short format.

Comment: @Arnauld This is what I meant yes

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toString(base)` to convert your base 10 numbers to your required base.e.g, hexadecimal (base 16)

```
function encode(input){
    var encoded = input.map(function(num){
       return num.toString(16);
    }).join('');
    return encoded;
}
```

Output:

> `>`encode([2, 0, 0, 0, 12]);
>
> '2000c'

Comment: If you're going to write a 'setter' you may as well offer a 'getter' as well, demo: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sbeu5rvc/)

Comment: @DavidThomas That's great. I actually wrote what OP asked. Thanks by the way

Comment: You did, I know - sorry if I phrased my comment badly - it was effectively just a gift that I thought might of some use, if included in the answer, rather than any kind of criticism. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas David, I am not an English speaker so if from my comment it seems like I am angry/offended, no, it's not. Your effort is most appreciated. event if you want to add, add an answer or edit mine.

Comment: I don't know who down voted my answer.. It works fine as for as I know

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I just removed my upvote, I was asking if there's a better solution, not how to implement it ;) anyway, thanks

Comment: @julesbou Ok, no problem